# Modem manager's ussd not working in Ubuntu 18.0

Tags: 18.04, modem-manager, ussd

I install modem manager Gui.

Everything works fine except USSD option.

I get this error
[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Uh7q.png)

then I try the command line

```
mmcli -m 0 --3gpp-ussd-initiate="*222#"
```

but I get same error.

```
error: couldn't initiate USSD session: 'GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.Core.Unsupported: Operation not supported.'
```

Can anyone help me to send ussd request?